# Simplifying MiniZinc constraints

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

I would like to simplify a group of repetitive constraints that appear in a model.
The aim is to ensure that a group of experts is staffed with a quantity of skills, each expert having 0..n skills.
Currently, I have to repeat the constraint for each skill in the set, but there is surely a way to simplify this with one "generic" constraint...

Relevant bit:

```
%Each group needs at least one expert with skill 1
constraint forall(g in Groups) (sum(e in Experts where expertskills[e,1]=1 \/ expertskills[e,2]=1) (assignment[g,e,1])>=1);
%Each group needs at least one expert with skill 2
constraint forall(g in Groups) (sum(e in Experts where expertskills[e,1]=2 \/ expertskills[e,2]=2) (assignment[g,e,2])>=1);
etc...
```

Comment: I guess that you can combine an extra loop (s in 1..num_skill) and then use bool2int() in the sum instead of the where clause. It would be easier to give detailed advice if you show a complete (but small) model.

Comment: Thank you.  I did not realize I could use nested "forall".  
With that, it is already looking better:
`constraint 
  forall(g in Groups) (
    forall(s in Skills)
      (sum(e in Experts where expertskills[e,1]=s \/ expertskills[e,2]=s) (assignment[g,e,s])>=1)
    );`
Now I need to figure out out to make the index / disjunctions in the expert skills array independent of the number of skills.
I can share the model with you Hakank, but would prefer to do it privately.

Comment: Looks like it can be made completely generic this way: `%Each group requires at least n experts with skill s
%groupskills[g,s] is the amount of skills s required in group g   
constraint 
  forall(g in Groups) (
    forall(s in Skills)
      (sum(e in Experts, i in Skills where expertskills[e,i]=s) (assignment[g,e,s])>=groupskills[g,s]) 
    );` 
Tested. Works.